# Python Results Differ To Anaconda-Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

We have a few windows PC's and recently had to rebuild one including reinstalling Python and Anaconda (both latest versions).
When I attempted to run some pre-existing Python scripts that worked previously on the machine (and work on the other PC's), I noticed a number of unexpected errors when attempting to run the scripts in Sublime Text/Python yet they work as expected in Jupyter.
I have tried un-installing, re-installing the Python/libraries/Sublime text, as well as tried using older release/versions.
A simple example is shown below for illustration of the problem. While I can remove regex=True to get the same result (and fix the issue), this example was chosen to illustrate the differences.

```
import pandas as pd 

# assign data of lists.  
data = {'Ticker': ['AAL', 'BRK.A', 'DAL', 'INTC']}  
  
# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  

print(df,'\n')

df['Ticker'] = df['Ticker'].str.replace('.','-', regex=True)
  
# Print the output.  
print(df)
```

[Output of script - Python vs Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guOyn.png)

Another issue is that I receive errors when calculating the number of days a trade was held (subtracting one date from another) yet this works fine on the other machines with the same dataframe and data.

```
df_trades['Days Held'] = (df_trades['Exit Date'] - df_trades['Date']).dt.days
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Windows10i\Desktop\20230408 Backtest Design Optimised BEST ATM.py", line 865, in <module>
    df_trades['Days Held'] = (df_trades['Exit Date'] - df_trades['Date']).dt.days
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Windows10i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5989, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Windows10i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py", line 224, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Windows10i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\accessors.py", line 580, in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values. Did you mean: 'at'?
```

Apologies in advance if this is a stupid question or has been answered before (I did search).
My goal is to understand (and hopefully fix) the Python/Sublime Text install so that the same results occur on all PC's. The code above is not the problem per se but more to illustrate that I am receiving different results and I would like to understand why and what I have done/ not done to cause the differences.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In regex '.' is a wildcard character that captures most things with some exceptions, so a substitution with '-' would turn most characters into '-'. I cannot recreate this behaviour without providing a compiled regex pattern in my python 3.11. So my assumption is the pandas behaviour is what's different, not the interpreter itself. The difference is on the left re.sub is being used and on the right str.replace is being used, despite the flag set being the same. Could you maybe provide the pandas version as well?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Friskod.Pandas in Python/Sublime Text was/is

pandas             2.0.1
pandas-datareader  0.10.0
pandas-ta          0.3.14b0

Pandas in Jupyter notebook was 1.4.2. When I upgraded Jupyter Pandas to 2.0.1, I receive the same output so I think the root cause has been found and it is time to revisit and amend some scripts to align to more recent packages.
Thanks very much for the prompt response and resolution - you are a star!!!